# ¿Como Graficar datos de MySQL en android Kotlin?

Tags: php, android, mysql, kotlin

Como puedo crear una grafica en android kotlin usando PHP para consultar los datos almacenados en MySQL en un servidor Externo? Alguien tiene un ejemplo. Gracias

Comment: Hola Damian..., aunque esta pregunta es interesante, también es demasiado amplia (y basada en opiniones) para el sitio. Intenta editarla para añadir algo más de información: ¿qué has investigado al respecto? ¿Has probado algo? ¿Con qué problemas o dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 1):

En tu pregunta no hay código así que no voy a proveer un ejemplo, sí te voy a decir como lo podés hacer:

1) En el lado del servidor, con PHP, necesitás que el script que invoques devualva, por ejemplo, un archivo `json`, con los datos a graficar. Esto puede ser que envíes las series. Para hacer eso lo mas simple es colocar dos datos de la serie en un array asociativo y generar el `json` con `json_encode(array())`

2) De lado de Android, necesitás traer los datos del servidor. Para hacer esto hay múltiples librerías que podés usar: `Volley`,  `Retrofit`, o alguna otra que conozcas. Vos verás en que momento querés actualizar los datos, es decir, ante que evento(s) vas a invocar el php en el servidor para que te llegue un nuevo set de información.

3) Una vez recibidos los datos los tenés que decodificar del `json`. Podés tratar directamente con el `json` usando la librería `jackson` por ejemplo, o modelar los datos en clases y usar `gson` que a mi juicio es más simple. Una vez hecho esto vas a contar con un una lista de datos numéricos a graficar.

4) Para hacer el gráfico yo utilizo una librería que se llama `MPCharts`. Vas a tener que agregala al proyecto en el `gradle` de la aplicación, en github explica como hacerlo y está toda la documentación del proyecto (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). En este punto vas a tener que ver la documentación y prepara los datos a plotear según el gráfico que elijas. Por ejemplo si mandaste dos series, una que refleja el eje x y otra el eje y de un gráfico cartesiando, tendrás que recorrer las dos listas y armar los puntos a plotear. Tal vez el gráfico que elijas, te haga cambiar como mandas los datos en el json, tal vez elijas enviar los puntos ya calculados en lugar de series separadas.
Una vez que le des una leída lo vas a ver más claro.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.

Comment: @Jorgesys Mirá si no querés que la pregunta se responda la podes bloquear o borrar tenes el perfil para hacerlo. No veo porque descalificas mi respuesta si la misma responde lo que se pregunta. Y no se trata que ahora le busques el pelo al huevo para tener razón porque sabés a que me refiero. Me parece que se te va un poco la mano en el rol que tenés, no es la primera vez. Eso aleja a la gente que quiere colaborar.

Comment: Es importante revises [ask] y [answer] esto para que nos ayudes a evitar contenido de "baja calidad" en el sitio. Hay que ayudar al OP a realizar una pregunta adecuadamente para que sea de utilidad a la comunidad. Recuerda agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces ya que estos pueden ser eliminados y no ayudarían a la respuesta.